# Show loading Screen while Image is loading in wicket

Tags: wicket

I'am populating a `ListView` with images.

In pseudocode:

```
populateItem(model){
    load base64 from database
    image.setDefaultModel(base64)
```

The image is just a `webcomponent` and in html it is just `<img src="">`
How can i show a indicator while the image is loaded?.
I first thought of adding `IAjaxIndicatorAware` but this triggers the indicator when the image is doing an `AjaxRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to load and display the image as a Base64 src it will directly get send in the html response and not loaded later (in contrast to images with a src that links to another URI).

You could wrap the image in an [AjaxLazyLoadPanel](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/index.html?org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLazyLoadPanel.html).
This will first display an AjaxIndicator while the content is generated and get later replaced by the actual loaded content once it is done loading/generating:

**edit**

> I got an Exception : Component must be applied to a tag of type [img].

i didn't consider that problem. AjaxLazyLoadPanel allways uses a `<div>` as a html tag to display the component it loads. To display a base 64 image you would need to wrap it in another Panel:

```
public class Base64ImagePanel extends Panel {
     public Base64ImagePanel(String wicketId, String base64Data, String contentType) {
          super(wicketId);
          WebMarkupContainer image = new WebMarkupContainer("image") {
                protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
                      super.onComponentTag(tag);
                      checkComponentTag(tag, "img");
                      tag.put("src", "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + base64Data);
                }
          }
          add(image);
     }
}
```

Base64ImagePanel.html:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <img wicket:id="image"></img>
</wicket:panel>
```

And then  use that wrapper Panel in the AjaxLazyLoadPanel:

```
add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("imageLazyLoad") {
    @Override
    public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String id) {
         //load your actual base64 from database, i use some example Strings for demonstration in the following line
         Base64ImagePanel imagePanel = new Base64ImagePanel(id, "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", "image/png");
         return imagePanel;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, I can see the AjaxIndicator but when the loading is done I got an Exception : Component must be applied to a tag of type [img]. I wrapped my image like this : <div wicket-id="lazy> <img src=""/></div>. However this answered my question!

Comment: @greedsin yeah sry, i didn't think about that problem. Since AjaxLazyLoadPanel allways uses a div to display it's lazy loaded Element you would need to wrap the image in another Panel and then return that Panel as a component to make it work. I edited the answer to show how it would be possible. Of course you would have to adapt it to work for you (since you only provided pseudo code and i don't know how exactly you construct your image) but it should be enough to get the idea across.